# Why doesn't Chrome display HTTP response code descriptions for HTTP/2 requests?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, http2

I've noticed that for all HTTP/2 requests, Chrome just gives a plain number for status codes instead of the code with the description:

**HTTP/1.1**
[image: HTTP/1.1]

**HTTP/2**
[image: HTTP/2]

Firefox does display these status code descriptions so it seems perfectly possible.  Why doesn't Chrome?

Comment: See the top two links [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=http2+status+text): HTTP2 doesn't provide status text.

Comment: Kind of annoying that Chrome doesn't add them in again for convenience.